# Code executing on only a few entries and missing entries that pass the rule?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, missing-data

Good Morning,

I have a database of safety data sheets for the benefit of COSHH, i am trying to create a function in which the user can enter a date into "H7" and any entried with dates less than that one will have the entire row transferred into sheet2.

the code i have written is as below

```
Sub checkdatasheets()
Dim datefrom As Variant

'select first entry
Sheet1.Range("E2").Select

'continue until an empty cell is reached
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then GoTo skipto:

'aquire date parameter
 datefrom = Sheet1.Range("H7")

 'if revision date is less than the date parameter copy and add to sheet2
  If ActiveCell.Value <= datefrom Then

        ActiveCell.Rows.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

 End If

'move onto next cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

skipto: MsgBox "Missing Data Sheet"

End Sub
```

The issue i am having is that this code takes certain rows but lots of rows are missed, even though they are less than the datefrom variable?

Thank you in advance for your help, any feedback on the writing of my code would be appreciated.

Comment: Your line `Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""` will exit the sub when it identifies an empty cell below the active cell. Your code is only working until it sees a blank cell then shows the message and stops. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: There are no gaps, it runs until the last entry in the database and extracts only certain items. Thank you for your criticism though. I am learning a lot from members on here and am close to solving my issue.

Comment: For your project I would filter using the date as the criteria, then copy the visible cells and paste to the first empty cell in Sheet2 Col A. It would be much quicker.

Comment: GMalc thank you so much, that does seem like a valid option, my concern is that i want to not just get dates from a certain year but all dates from before a selected date. I am close to solving the issue using Error 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the below code in the change event of the sheet which you will import the date.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sDate As Date
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Long

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

        If IsDate(Target.Value) Then
            sDate = CDate(Target.Value)
            LastRow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 3 To LastRow1
                If CDate(Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value) < sDate Then
                    LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Sheet1.Rows(i).Copy Sheet2.Rows(LastRow2 + 1)
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            MsgBox "Please insert a valid date."
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

**Sheet 1 (includes the date)**

[image]

**Sheet 2 (Results)**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Error 1004, i have amended this to search via the correct column and it is doing exactly what is needed and pretty quickly too! I'm trying to dissect and fully understand what exactly is happening within the code and think I get it. Thanks once again for your help this will prove very helpful for the admin staff who need to upkeep the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using select and also reference your sheets better. Something like code below should work better allready:

```
Sub checkdatasheets2()

For X = 2 To Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheets(1).Cells(X, 5).Value < Sheets(1).Cells(7, 8).Value Then
        Sheets(1).Rows(X).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you JvdV, unfortunately this is bringing up the exact same results as before. although the date in 7,8 is 01/01/2019 and EVERY entry in the database is before that date, it still only selects about 8 out of 354 sheets.(I will try to avoid .select) unfortunately that is a way I understand the code a little better. (At quite a basic level at the moment and trying not to cut/paste without understanding what the code is doing)

Comment: @SeanHickman, what are the cells formatted like then? Are they not all dates?

Comment: That was my first port of call but they're all formatted to Date - 01/01/19, thank you for your help as I have now understood the way of using xlup to count rows and add to the bottom which is LOADS faster than my previous way.

Comment: Iterate through the code using F8. Report back what rownumber it stops working according to what it should do, that is the first row where apparently the value should be lower but really isn't. Then tell us if you can tell any difference in format/value or otherwise.

Comment: It runs throughout the whole workbook until there are no blank cells and even reads values that should be copied, it just doesn't do them. I'm getting close to my solution with Error 1004's suggestion. Thank you for your help though. I will be avoiding .select in future.